# Use WCF service without proxy client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I have an application which can just send SOAP messages and parse responses. My WCF service works fine if i use proxy client, but i need to have ability just send POST request in SOAP format as it was in old ASMX services. Is there any possibility to do it?

I tried copy SOAP request from debug wcf client and send it as POST request with Content-Type text/xml but it doesn't give me a correct result.

Comment: Why you are not using RESTful Services? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

Comment: @Reno, does RESTful services supports SOAP format? Because WebGet and WebInvoke attributes supports XML and JSON request / response formats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can call them using a "plain" HTTP request - after all, as far as the server is concerned all it receives are bytes in a TCP connection. Depending on the binding which you're using, you may also need to set some HTTP header - if you're using BasicHttpBinding on your service, you'll also need to set the `SOAPAction` header. Try sending your request, and your request from a client using a WCF proxy, and compare them in a tool such as Fiddler. If the requests are the same, the server will respond them the same as well.

Comment: thanks! i really missed SOAPAction header. Damn, i wasted 3 days to find solution)

Answer (score 3):

When I need to pass the full soap message by http web request, I use SoapUI.  You can give it a WSDL and it does what the proxy does for code, but instead generates soap xml.  And as @carlosfigueira mentioned you will want to look in the HTTP Headers section and set them appropriately.

[www.soapui.org](http://www.soapui.org/)